# How can we save our yucca plant?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care

We recently inherited a yucca plant that looks like it might be struggling.

The only healthy growth is at the very top of the highest branches/trunk, and the ends of the branches where it has most recently been cut back are an odd shape (you can just about see this with the closest branch in the photo below). The tips of the leaves are also blackened and dry.

Is there any way we can encourage more growth, particularly lower down on the plant, as we're concerned if all the growth is high up, then it will quickly become unbalanced? What can we do to revitalise him? How quickly should we be expecting it to grow at this time of year in the UK?

[image]

Comment: Yuccas usually send up new sprouts, all the way from the ground. This happens in the spring time.

Comment: We've had it for about 3 months now and haven't seen anything like that

Answer (score 1):

That is a dracaena , a very hardy tolerant plant. Possibly dry to cause the leaf curl. Have you changed something ?

Comment: It looks like a Yucca palm to me.